# Is this just a nested For Loop?

Tags: c

Came across this code the other day:

```
for(i=0; i<r1; ++i)
for(j=0; j<r1; ++j)
for(k=0; k<r1; ++k){
    mult[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
}
```

Now, is this just a different way of writing:

```
for(i=0; i<r1; ++i){
    for(j=0; j<r1; ++j){
        for(k=0; k<r1; ++k){
            mult[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are the same. Why didn't you just test it out yourself?

Comment: because it's not a real question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes that is correct .. Put brackets around the first implementation to see for yourself.

PS - there is no one right way  .. but I would highly recommend using brackets always ( especially if you are new to programming ) .

It goes a long way to help you understand and debug the code

Comment: @JonathonReinhart that is correct

Comment: I believe he means *braces*. Array notation uses brackets.

Comment: The terms "bracket" and "brace" are used differently in different parts of the world, particularly US vs. UK. In US usage, these `{` `}` are *braces* and these `[` `]` are *brackets*. I make no claim that US usage is "correct", but it's clearer to show the actual characters.

Comment: Actually, parenthesis `( )`, braces/curly brackets `{ }`, square brackets `[ ]` are all forms of [*brackets*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket). Microsoft Equation Editor also uses this definition ([see image](http://i.imgur.com/YgPk08p.png)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The syntax for `for` is

```
for (init-statement; condition; iteration_expression)
    statement
```

and `for` is itself an statement. Therefor it can make a recursive compound.

---

You can even drop last `{}`:

```
for(i=0; i<r1; ++i)
  for(j=0; j<r1; ++j)
    for(k=0; k<r1; ++k)
      mult[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
```

Indentation is very important to make the code readable.

Comment: But the philosophical question is, should you drop the braces. :D

Comment: Where there's really only one line of computation like this, I would omit the brackets.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I wouldn't.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart you should try not to .. makes it easy for someone looking at your code to decipher what it is that you are writing ...

Comment: @sukhvir In this specific case, I would argue the opposite: The brackets add nothing, and omitting them makes it easier to read. But this is a decades-old argument, not really worth having.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart haha agreed